# Java AWT - last button added not showing up

Tags: java, button, awt

For some reason the last added button does not get displayed. I tried reordering them but still the same result. I checked the coordinates and they are correct.

The last 3 is where I get the problem. The last "add" button doesn't get displayed.

```
public class MainScreen extends Frame implements MouseListener{

HowToPlay otherFrame;
Button start, howto, settings, about ;
Image MainMenu;

MainScreen(){

Toolkit tkMM = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
MainMenu = tkMM.getImage(this.getClass().getResource("MainMenu.jpg"));

    otherFrame = new HowToPlay();

Button start = new Button ("Start Game");
    start.setBounds(98, 333, 326, 51);

Button howto = new Button ("How to Play");
    howto.setBounds(98, 389, 326, 29);
    howto.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            setVisible(false);
            otherFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

Button settings = new Button ("Settings");
    settings.setBounds(98, 424, 326, 29);

Button about = new Button ("About");
    about.setBounds(98, 462, 326, 29);

        about.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            setVisible(false);
            otherFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

        add(start); 
        add(howto);
        add(settings);
        add(about);



    setVisible(true);
    setSize(500, 500);
    setResizable(false);
    setLayout(null);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);  // Center the frame
    setSize(500,500);//size of the canvass
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
            super.windowClosed(e);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: We need a *lot* more information.  No one can possibly discern anything from what you've posted so far.  What is that `add` method you're calling?  To what type of container is it adding components?  What LayoutManager does that container use?

Comment: Updated with the complete one.

Comment: You still need a lot more code.

Comment: Updated my code. By the way, the instructions were only to use AWT. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Don't use a `null` layout and `setBounds`. 2. Instead nest Panels, each using a layout of choice. 3. Why AWT and not at least Swing?

Comment: Project restriction by my professor. :-(

Comment: A quick but lame solution is just to add another empty button after the about. ie add(about); add(new Button());

Comment: Wow nice it worked. Still puzzled by the disappearing button problem though. :-)

Comment: @rgstrdnny, hope you didn't use the suggestion by Will (adding an extra component). Using a null layout is bad enough. I would fail you for that solution. `the instructions were only to use AWT.` Well, layout managers exist in AWT. That is the solution you should be using.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're calling `setLayout(null);` at the end after adding all components. To fix this, call it at the beginning:

```
MainScreen() {
    setLayout(null);

    Toolkit tkMM = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    //.....
```

Having said that I strongly urge you to avoid use of `null` layouts and `setBounds`

e.g.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MainScreen2 extends Panel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 500;
    private static final int PREF_H = 500;

    public MainScreen2() {
        Panel bottomPanel = new Panel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        bottomPanel.add(new Button("Start Game"));
        bottomPanel.add(new Button("How To Play"));
        bottomPanel.add(new Button("Settings"));
        bottomPanel.add(new Button("About"));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Frame frame = new Frame("MainScreen2");
        frame.add(new MainScreen2());
        frame.pack();
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                super.windowClosed(e);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: (1+) simple solution, although. I think students should be failed for using a null layout. I wish professor's would get with it.

Answer (score 1):

> Wow nice it worked. Still puzzled by the disappearing button problem though.

The default layout manager is a BorderLayout.

When you add components to a BorderLayout without specifying a constraint the component will be added to the CENTER. However, only one component can be added to the center, so the last one added (the "about" button) will be handled by the layout manager.

When you invoke the `setVisible(true)` method, the layout manager is invoked and the "about" button is given a size/location. All the other buttons are ignored because the BorderLayout doesn't care about them.

However, the size of the frame is (0, 0) so there is no space to allocate to the "about" button so it is given a height of 0, which effectively means there is nothing to paint.

So when the frame is painted the other 3 buttons a painted properly but not the "about" button.

Change the code to:

```
setSize(500, 500);
setVisible(true);
```

and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The default layout manager for Frame is BorderLayout. When you use add(item) that item is placed in center, replacing anything that was there.
You need to use a different layout manager

Comment: He's already using a different manager. He's setting layout to `null`.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The components are being added to a BorderLayout, and *then* `setLayout(null)` is called.  Calling `setLayout(null)` before any calls to `add` will fix the problem.